# Expanding PHP execution time limit

Tags: php, time, limit, execution

I have a question about PHP's execution time limit. I need to run a script for many hours sending HTTP requests. These requests have to be apart a certain time, so that's why the whole thing is supposed to take hours. Does someone have experience setting this kind of time limit for PHP using the line below? For example:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 28800);    // 8 hours
```

Strange question, I know, but let me know if this would work or not. TIA!

Update: I was going to try it from the browser. I'm not familiar with running PHP scripts from the command line.. I should look into this. I did found an alternate way to get this information that could be retrieved from the HTTP request; It turns out we have a database with some of the information already locally accumulated over a long period of time.

Comment: I usually do this on with php from the command line (i.e. no webserver), with no time-limit _at all_.

Comment: You can too use the flush() and ob_flush() functions. for flush the output buffer. 
and use set_time_limit(0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running this from browser or from CLI? If from CLI (as you should with such script), there is no exection time limit (i.e. `max_execution_time` is hardcoded to 0)

Comment: I run my PHP scripts from the browser. How do you run it from the CLI?

Comment: Open you console and type: `php yourScript.php`

Answer (score 2):

```
set_time_limit(28800);
```

some (shared)hosts do not allow this

what i will suggest you is maintain a log of when was your last attempt (unix time stamp), and use cron to execute a script which checks if its time to make the next HTTP request, and if yes then update the timestamp in the file to current time stamp.

Hope that helps

Comment: `set_time_out()` is not a PHP function (do you mean `set_time_limit()`?). Scripts executed from the command-line (e.g. via cron) do not have a execution time limit.

Comment: @chris thanks for telling, i corrected the function name there, and for the second part, OP didnt said anywhere that its CLI... :-/

Comment: No, but it will be if you're executing the script via cron, as your answer suggests. :)

Comment: @chris well, yeah u r right, but the purpose of cron is different here, i dont mean to suggest the use of set_time_limit(28800); with cron... basically the idea of running the script 8 hours seems pretty inefficient, so i suggest small cron runs and checking the last HTTP request time and making the next HTTP request accourdingly... so no changing of time limit... and the script will be short.

Comment: @Pheonix, I'm running this on localhost. "con job" did come across my research on how to implement this, but this is something I need to learn. I'm not familiar with it. Someone suggested this type of scripts be run on CLI, but I don't know that either. I'm very much a PHP novice.